# Перегруженные операции и const&

Tags: c++

11.6 Бьерн Страуструп

```
class Matrix
{
   //...
   friend Matrix& operator+(const Matrix&, const Matrix&)
}
```

> Бьерн Страуструп: "...Результат будет скорей всего размещаться в свободной памяти..."

Oн подразумевает под "Свободная память" - уже деконструированной.

Но есть ведь правило, если привязать временный объект к ссылке на const в стеке, то жизнь временного объекта будет продлена. Он будет жить столько, сколько живет константная ссылка на него.

```
Martix a;
Matrix b;
Matrix с;

a + (b + c); //Преобразуется в:
operator+(a, operator+(b, c));
```

Корректен этот код?

UPD: Вообщем, итог вопроса, я не правильно воспринял правило.

```
string f() { return "йух"; }

int main() {
  const string& s = f();
  cout << s << endl;    
}
```

А вот так оно не работает:

```
string& f() { return "йух"; }

int main() {
  const string& s = f();
  cout << s << endl;    
}
```

Comment: У меня нет под рукой книги, чтобы проверить, что имеется в виду. Но, похоже, так как оператор возвращает ссылку на Matrix, то соответствующий объект "скорей всего размещается  в свободной памяти", то есть в динамической области памяти.  Иначе ссылка на объект будет невеоной, так как сам объект будет уже удален.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я не могу проверить контекст приведенного высказывания, так как не имею под рукой данной книги, но, похоже, имеется в виду следующее.

Так как оператор возвращает ссылку на объект, то этот объект должен быть "живым" при выходе из функции. Иначе ссылка будет недействительной. Например, этот объект не может быть локальной переменной оператора, так как при завершении работы оператора локальные переменные будут разрушены и станут "неживыми".

Поэтому скорей всего этот объект находится в динамически распределенной памяти, которая в приведенной цитате называется "свободной памятью".

В этом случае результат работы оператора придется также присваивать ссылке, чтобы затем можно было бы удалить объект из динамически распределенной памяти.

Например,

```
Matrix a;
Matrix b;

Matrix &c = a + b;
//...
delete &c;
```

Конечно правильно было бы объявить оператор следующим образом

```
friend Matrix operator+(const Matrix&, const Matrix&);
```

или

```
friend const Matrix operator+(const Matrix&, const Matrix&);
```

а не создавать объект в динамической области памяти и возвращать ссылку на него.

Что касается связывания ссылки с временным объектом, то можно связать лишь константную ссылку. Причем этот временный объект должен быть создан в той же области определения, что и сама ссылка. В случае данного объявления оператора

```
friend Matrix & operator+(const Matrix&, const Matrix&);
```

временный объект создается внутри функции (если это временный объект, а не объект в области динамической памяти), а ссылка определена в области вызова оператора. Поэтому ссылка будет недействительной, как я уже описал выше, в виду разрушения временного объекта по завершению работы функции.

Вот демонстрационный пример того, что я имел в виду

```
#include <iostream>

struct Matrix
{
    explicit Matrix( int x = 0 ) : x ( x ) {}
    int x;
};

Matrix & operator +( const Matrix &a, const Matrix &b )
{
    return *new Matrix( a.x + b.x );
}    

int main()
{
    Matrix &c = Matrix( 10 ) + Matrix( 20 );

    std::cout << c.x << std::endl;

    delete &c;
}
```

Вывод программы на консоль:

```
30
```

Чтобы было более понятно, то если у вас есть функция, объявленная как

```
T f();
```

то объект типа `T` будет создаваться в области вызова функции. Вы можете представить вызов функции `f()` следующим образом

```
T temporary_object = f();
```

только на самом деле `T temporary_object` это некоторый неименованный временный объект. Если его не присвоить какому-то другому объекту в области вызова функции, то он будет уделен.

Следующий вызов

```
T x;

x = f();
```

может условно выглядеть следующим образом

```
T x;

T temporary_object = f();

x = temporary_object;
```

**EDIT:** Если в приведенной цитате под "свободной памятью" имеется в виду уже высвобожденная память, то значит ссылка ссылается на уже разрушенный "неживой" объект. То есть ссылка недействительна. И даже если бы эта ссылка была константной, она также была бы недействительной, так как определена за пределами того блока кода, где был определен временный объект. То есть той памяти, которая принадлежала этому блоку кода, можно сказать, уже не существует.

Comment: Он сослался на пункт 7.3, где рассказывает об том, что нельзя возвращать ссылку на автоматическую переменную из функции.  Из этого можно сделать вывод, он говорил о свободной памяти как о уже деконструированной после завершения работы функции. И правило работает только при константной ссылке.

Comment: "Причем этот временный объект должен быть создан в той же !области определения!, что и сама ссылка." Не понял.

Comment: Автор книги говорил об коде как об некорректном.

Comment: @uskabuska Например, в этот фрагменте кода int x = 10; int &r = x + 5; временный объект x + 5 создается в той же области определения, что и сама ссылка. А если вы напишите int & f() { int x = 10; return x + 5' }, то временный объект создается в области определения кодового блока функции, тогда как ссылка, то есть ссылка, соответствующая типу возвращаемого объекта создается в области определения вызова функции. Тип возвращаемого значения функции - это тип того объекта, который будет создан за пределами самой функции в области ее вызова.

Comment: "int &r = x + 5;" - такое не сработает, тут rvalue. PS: Еще разбираюсь с вашим комментарием.

Comment: @uskabuska Это опечатка. Должно быть const int &r = x + 5;

Comment: @uskabuska Тип возвращаемого объекта функции - это то, что создается за пределами функции в той области определения, где функция вызывается. то, что создается внутри тела функции, принадлежит этому телу функции. По завершению работы функции, условно можно сказать, что вся ее память уничтожается, и в области вызова у вас оказывается "подвисшая" ссылка, которая ссылается на память, которая уже не существует.

Comment: @uskabuska Что касается кода на ideone, то он как раз и демонстрирует то, что я написал: как можно условно представить вызов функции. Читайте внимательно мой ответ.

Comment: Спасибо, до меня дошло. Надо проспаться :DD Я просто не правильно воспринял правило, стыдно. А про принцип возвращение из функции объекта я уже давно знал.